# Have selection functions with "maximum-like" properties been studied before?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I've been playing around with "selection" functions that map finite nonempty sets to one of their elements. The maximum function, e.g. over finite sets of integers, is one such function with some interesting properties:

- If $\max(A) = \max(B) = m$, then $\max(A \cup B) = \max(A \cap B) = m$
- If you successively pick and remove the maximum of a set, you will get a uniquely defined last remaining element which happens to be the minimum. Applying the same procedure to a set but using the minimum function, gives you the maximum again. The max and min functions are dual in this sense.

There are other functions that have these properties of max/min (aside from ones that are just max/min with permuted elements), for example the function that picks the largest number $x \in S$ such that $x - 1 \notin S$.

Have functions with these or similar properties been studied before?

Answer (score 0):

You might have well-ordered sets in mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order. Every subset of a well ordered set has a minimum. This leads to the concept of the next element (remove the smallest one). Which can be used to find the maximum in case of finite set.
But orderings on finite sets seem a bit boring, as they are all well ordered if you have a total order.